# Detect If Browser Tab is focused on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, mobile, visibility

I am willing to detect if the tab is in focus on as many mobile browsers as possible.

I saw that the common use in determining visibility is **"document.hidden"** or **"document.visibilityState"**, but on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/hidden#Browser_compatibility is listed that it's **not compatible on IE mobile**.

Found also that many use **document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {})** - which also seems to might not be compatible on IE Mobile.

Another less common use is **document.hasFocus()** which is not supported in Opera Mini and might not be supported in Safari and Mobile Chrome..

plus, the "window.onblur" doesn't seem to work on chrome emulator.

Anyone knows maybe another way to check if the browser is in focus on all mobile browsers? or maybe one of  the above is actually compatible to all?

Comment: IE mobile is outdated. Windows phone holds less than 1% of the smartphone market. It might be worth it to use document.hidden or document.visibilityState and not support the ever shrinking userbase that uses IE mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the two events:

`window.onfocus` and `window.onblur`?

You can associate code which triggers when it focuses and it blurs, so actually you can detect when it's not focused

Comment: Checked them in chrome emulator and the code went to the function associated with the window.onblur also when the page was focused

Comment: I added the same functions here in the page as example and it works. 
It actually prints the blur when you switch tab, then it outputs the focus when you come back to the tab

Comment: Just open the chrome console here in the page and add these functions with a console.log(), printing focus and blur respectively. 
You will notice that in the console you have the right outputs in the right order

Comment: I tried it on mobile responsive emulator in this page and it seems to start console.log only after I focus to the console tab, when I open a new tab and even focus on input fields on a different tab it still doesn't print "blur" if I didn't focus out to the console in this tab .

Comment: open the console here. 
Define the followings:
window.onfocus = function () { console.log('FOCUS'); }
window.onblur = function () { console.log('BLUR'); }

Then click on the page, click back in the console etc etc etc....
Tried again now and it works

Comment: if you switch tabs, without clicking in the console first, (what a user wouldn't do in a mobile device) do you still see it work?

Comment: sure, you just need to click the first time the page after you defined the script in the console. This is not your case because you will load the script immediately when opening the view.